# How to capture text formatting in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, colors, escape-characters

The following shell script works but removes colored formatting generated by `rspec`:

```
#!/bin/bash
OUTPUT=`rspec`
echo "$OUTPUT"
```

How to preserve the colors?

Comment: What is much more likely is `rspec` is simply not doing color formatting when not outputting directly to terminal.  You need to find an option like `--color=always` to force color.  The shell isn't stripping the color sequences - it doesn't even know how to do so.  Why are you trying to save colored output in a variable anyways?  Just output it directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's common for programs with colorized output to disable it if they're not being run directly in a TTY, since you might be piping the output to a log file or to another process that expects plain text. Typically the programs offer a switch to manually force colors enabled, and `rspec` has one (`--color`), but for some reason it ignores it if you're not running in a TTY, which is really unusual behavior.

I think your only options are to edit `rspec` to take out that check (see `def color` in `rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb`), or run it within a program that will trick it into thinking it has a TTY, like [`expect`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect)